# NO WIFI ADAPTER FOR RHEL 7.3

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, hp-pavilion, wifi-driver

I have been searching all the answers which revolve around the network adapter in Linux. Sadly, I am stuck where I started since none of the remedies was a breakthrough for me.
Output for `lspci | grep d723`

`2:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device d723`

I had even tried to set one of the 2 antenna and few other remedies but nothing seems to work.
I shall be highly obliged for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install the [drivers](https://github.com/smlinux/rtl8723de).

Comment: I did as it was directed in github.But still facing the same issue sadly.I am totally confused.

Comment: @KOUSHIKNAG I think you need this [kernel module](https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8723de)